# sqlite3 to csv & download to desktop

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database which resides in C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap (complete location = C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap/employee.db). I want to convert the database to csv and download it on my desktop.

Have checked the **user_desktop_path** which is correct(printed the location and it's giving me correct address of my desktop) ; however, can't confirm if the connection is successful or what went wrong...
Please help

```
def downloadRoster(self):
    user_desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
    response = messagebox.askyesno("Download | Roster After Swap", "Would you like to download the file?")
    if response == 'yes':
        connection = sqlite3.connect("C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap/employee.db")
        connection.text_factory = sqlite3.OptimizedUnicode
        sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_details"
        database_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
        database_dataframe.sort_values('Date', ascending = FALSE)
        database_dataframe.to_csv(user_desktop_path + "\Roster After Swap.csv", index = FALSE)
        messagebox.showinfo("Download", "Successfully downloaded at desktop location")

    elif response == 'no':
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your `sql` and fetch the results to see if the connection is successful. Here is an example which might help you:

```
   connection = sqlite3.connect("C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap/employee.db")
   sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_details;"   
   results = connection.execute(sql)
   results = results.fetchall()
   print(results)
   if results:
      # Your code here
   connection.close()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It worked out for me but I am unable to save the file in csv format anywhere. First I thought I should save it to desktop and gave following command...
user_desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

Comment: def downloadRoster():
        connection = sqlite3.connect("C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap/employee.db")
        sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_details;"
        database_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
        database_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
        database_dataframe.sort_values('Date')
        database_dataframe.to_csv("C:/"+ "Roster After Swap.csv", encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Above code won't save the file too.... but gives an error :

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Roster After Swap.csv'

Answer (score 0):

```
def downloadRoster( self ):
    connection = sqlite3.connect ( "C:/Projects/Advisor Roster Swap/employee.db" )
    sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_details;"
    database_dataframe = pd.read_sql_query ( sql , connection )
    database_dataframe.sort_values ( 'Date' )
    user_desktop_path = os.path.join ( os.path.join ( os.environ [ 'USERPROFILE' ] ) , 'Downloads' )
    self.destination_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename ( initialdir = "/" , title = "Select file" , filetypes = (
        ("CSV files" , "*.csv") , ("all files" , "*.*")) )
    database_dataframe.to_csv ( self.destination_path + ".csv" , index = FALSE )
    messagebox.showinfo ( "Download" , "Successfully Downloaded" )
    connection.commit ()
    connection.close ()
```